# Difference between CF particular solution general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have am solving a 2nd order differential equation and have been asked to give

- i) Complementary function
- ii) a particular solution
- iii) General solution

I just wanted to know whats the difference between particular solution and general solution

Answer (score 3):

Before I attempt to explain, let's look at an example $y''+3y'+2y=e^t$, where $y=y(t)$ is a function of $t$. Particular solution, which I denote here by $y_p(t)$ is the solution that satisfied the ODE. It can be shown that $\dfrac{1}{6}e^t$ satisfies the ODE, thus the particular solution is $y_p(t)=\dfrac{1}{6}e^t$. On the other hand, to obtain a complementary solution, which I denote here by $y_c(t)$, we need to solve the homogeneous part of the ODE (i.e. without the term $e^t$). It can be shown that $y_c(t)=Ae^{-t} + Be^{-2t}$, where $A,B$ are constants determined by the initial condition.

So here is the explanation. Particular solution is just a solution that satisfies the full ODE; general solution on the other hand is complete solution of a given ODE, which is the sum of complimentary solution and particular solution.

Comment: I get $y_c(x) = C_1 - \frac{2x}{3} - \frac{C_2 e^{-3x}}{3}$

Comment: Your $y_c(t)$ is the solution to $y''+3y'+2y=0$, not the $y''+3y'+2=0$ as written in your question. Which then makes $y_p(t) = \frac{e^t}{6}$.

Comment: @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin You were right, thanks!